# Databases ORM Doctrines Symfony 4

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, doctrine, symfony4

I just left the Symfony 4 doc to ask a question here.

I already have a database on phpmyadmin which contain 3 tables.

I correctly set the .env file with database information.

But I did not understand how doctrines link my database from phpmyadmin to my Symfony project.

I read the doc and they learn how to create databases entity etc ... from a new database but not from an already existing database.

Maybe I missed something.

Thanks for reading me.
Have a nice day!

Dopa.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a reverse engineering, You can try this command to generate entities from tables :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import 'App\Entity' annotation --path=src/Entity
```

For more details : https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html